# Save a rasterPCA plot as a raster file in R

Tags: raster, r, ggplot2

Looking to the tutorial in http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/rasterPCA.html, in which they show how to do a Principal Component Analysis on raster data, I was wandering whether is it possible to convert the ggRGB plot in a raster file.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slot `map` inside PCA result is a `RasterBrick`:

```
library(RStoolbox)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data(rlogo)

set.seed(25)

rpc <- rasterPCA(rlogo)

class(rpc$map)

[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

You can save this slot as a raster with `raster` package:

```
library(raster)

writeRaster(rpc$map, "rpc.tif")
```

You can set `bylayer = FALSE` if you want a multi-layer raster as output, default is `TRUE`.

Also, read function description:

> ### **Principal Component Analysis for Rasters**
>
> **Description**
> Calculates R-mode PCA for RasterBricks or RasterStacks and returns a RasterBrick with multiple layers of PCA scores.